# Cannot read data by Entity Framework 6 using IIS10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, iis-10

An Asp.net MVC 5 web app with Entity Framework 6, is published and hosted on IIS 10.

After publishing, I am able to login and register using build-in MVC services. However, accessing data by EF in db table all return empty results and adding exception would not throw any exception.

```
    IQueryable<Record> records=null;
        try
        {
            records= from m in _context.Record
                           select m;

        }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.Message, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.Message, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));
    }
    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));
```

Would glad to know any security setting can resolve.

Comment: That code doesn't do anything but create a query, and then not run it.  You'll need to post the relevant bits, including where you configure the connection string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ToList() is added and data is returned in vs2017. but when i publish the project to IIS is just return nothing. FYR, connection string in Desktop\webapplication2\Web.config :
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet5-WebApplication1-332f2d68-229a-485f-ad08-c72ac7ad7d6f;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0):

Start simpler, and use the debugger.

```
var query = _context.Records.AsQueryable();
var records = query.ToList();
return Json(records, JSonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

if you prefer the linq syntax:

```
var query = from r in _context.Records
            select r;
```

... put a break point on `var records = query.ToList();` and verify you are getting results. If you're getting results, then the issue may be feeding the `IQueryable` to Json. If you're still not getting results then double-check your connection string.

My recommendation is to avoid passing entities back to view logic, it's just fraught with issues that crop up with lazy loading and dealing with disconnected entities and re-associating entities with DbContexts on the round trip. I use entities for domain mapping, and view models for data representations for the view. The benefit is avoiding the above lazy-load, etc. issues, but also from a data over the wire perspective you typically don't need to send *every* value and child reference for each entity. View models reflect the data the view needs, and can be flattened as necessary from the domain.

```
var viewModels = _context.Records
    .Select(x => new RecordViewModel
    {
        RecordId = x.RecordId,
        //...
    }).ToList();
return Json(viewModels, JSonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You can utilize Automapper for instance to help manage the mapping between entity and view model.

Comment: var records = query.ToList();  works in vs2017, but when the project is published to iis, the result returned is still empty.

Connection string in IIS project's Web.config is same as the one in vs2017. This confuse me a lot:     <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet5-WebApplication1-332f2d68-229a-485f-ad08-c72ac7ad7d6f;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: That connection string looks odd. If you're publishing to IIS then the Integrated Security option will be connecting to the database using the Application Pool credentials. I'm assuming that this IIS instance you are running is still your own machine. If it's another machine then I'd be suspicious of that Initial Catalog (database name) You can run a test by seeing what application pool the app is configured to run, and set it to your own account. (*not* for production! :) )